# Firebase API - even i added cors on my express server, i'm still getting cors error. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, api, cors

i am trying to create an express - api with firestore database. But only thing i got is CORS errors. Here is the API code ; `

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});


const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")


//Main app
const app = express()
app.use(cors({origin:true}));

//Main database reference
const db = admin.firestore()

//Routes
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    return res.status(200).send('Hello, world!')
})
//Create => post()
app.post("/api/create", (req,res) => {
    (async () => {
        try{
            await db.collection('userDetails').doc(`/${Date.now()}/`).create({
                id: Date.now(),
                name: req.body.name,
                mobile:req.body.mobile,
                address: req.body.address
            })
            return res.status(200).send({status:'Success', msg: 'Data Saved'})
        }catch(err){

        }
    })()
})


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

`

And the error is : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myApi' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Thanks already, have a great day/night !

I'm trying to get the data from api, but im getting CORS error.
[Network tab error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK6Bg.png)

---

**Well, i'm kinda dumb i guess. It wasn't the backend code but frontend. I had typo when im doing the api call. Backend code is working fine.**

Comment: Edit your question and add a screenshot of the problematic request/response from your browser's Network tab.

Comment: You've added a screenshot of the response, but what about the request?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
app.use(cors({origin:true}))
```

to

```
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: It didn't work :/